# Windows batch file - string comparison with wildcard

Tags: batch-file

I have a file `myFile.txt` with a bunch of strings. I wrote the following batch file to loop through the lines, and print a line if it equals a specific string (for the sake of demo, I now choose the string `foo`):

```
    @echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    for /f %%i in (myFile.txt) do (

        line=%%i
        if !line! EQU foo* (
            echo !line!
        ) 

    )
```

In my application, I not only need to print lines that exactly match `foo`, but also those lines that match `fooBar`, `fooBarFred`, `fooFred`, ... That's why I put a wildcard there.

But it doesn't work..

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
findstr /b "foo" myfile.txt
```

`/b`: line should start with the string

also might be useful:

`/i`: ignore capitalization (find foo, Foo, fOO, ...)

See `findstr /?` for more options

Comment: Thank you Stephan. Your suggestion to use `findstr /?` was really helpful :-)

Answer (score 3):

There are no wildcards allowed for string compares.

You can simplify it by substring your line.
But first you should fix your code.
It must be `set line=%%i` not `line=%%i`.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "delims=" %%i in (myFile.txt) do (
    set "line=%%i"
    set "first=!line:~0,3!"
    if "!first!" EQU "foo" (
        echo(!line!
    ) 
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Why does your for-loop start with `for /f "delims="...` ?

Comment: because standard delimters are SPACE and TAB. Without disabling delims, you'll get the first word only.